# Bayesian meta-analysis: Why and how to weight individual study's contribution to overall effect?

Tags: bayesian, python, meta-analysis, hierarchical-bayesian, pymc

I'm interested in performing a Bayesian meta-analysis, specifically, using a random-effects hierarchical model (as described [here](https://bookdown.org/MathiasHarrer/Doing_Meta_Analysis_in_R/bayesian-ma.html)). Briefly, in this model we assume that the $k$th study's reported (observed) effect size $\hat{\theta}_k$ is an estimate of that study's true effect size $\theta_k$. Further, all $\theta_k$ are considered samples from a higher-level distribution that describes the true overall effect size. The mean of this higher-level distribution $\mu$ is what we're most interested in. So, we have:

$$\hat{\theta}_k \sim N(\theta_k, \sigma^2_k)$$
$$\theta_k \sim N(\mu, \tau^2)$$

In the section of the tutorial describing how to fit the model, the authors write: *"Furthermore, we cannot simply use the effect size of each study...as is. We also have to give studies with higher precision (i.e. sample size) a greater weight."*

I'm confused by this because I thought the observed standard error $\sigma_k$ we use in the likelihood already weights each individual study's contribution to the estimate of the overall effect $\mu$ (i.e., the smaller $\sigma_k$, the more study $k$ will contribute to the estimate of $\mu$). That is, don't we get that for "free" using Bayes' theorem?

Next, if you can explain why I should take an *extra* step to weight each study by its precision, can you also explain the mechanics of how you do that? I'm using Python and PyMC rather than R, so it will be extra appreciated if the explanation does NOT involve R-brms syntax.

**Note:** Below is what I have within the PyMC model definition, where `theta_obs` and `sigma_obs` denote each study's reported effect size and standard error (i.e., $\hat{\theta}_k$ and $\sigma_k$ from the equations above):

```
# Hyper-priors
mu_theta = pm.Normal("mu_theta", mu=0, sigma=1)
tau = pm.Exponential("tau", lam=1)

# Priors
theta = pm.Normal("theta", mu=mu_theta, sigma=tau,  shape=n_studies)

# Likelihood
theta_hat = pm.Normal('theta_hat', mu=theta, sigma=sigma_obs, observed=theta_obs)
```

The estimated parameters seem reasonable, so I think I'm on the right track, but appreciate any feedback regarding weighting each study.

Comment: I think you are right. 

That clarification from the authors is an artifact of the dataset being one row per the study, where each row has an effect size and a standard error. brms expects the raw data (one row per observation), so they explicitly need to specify the standard errors of each effect size.

In PyMC we tend to use raw data (I don't know how to fit a Normal distribution with observed summary/sufficient statistics), so this might be adding to the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Fernando. I've added the relevant lines of my PyMC model definition above, in case it's helpful. Note that I'm also treating each study as a single observation and defining the likelihood's sigma with each study's reported sigma. We treat each study as a single observation because we only have summary statistics to work with (it would not be feasible to get raw data from all studies entering the meta-analysis). But I still think the studies get automatically "weighted" through the reported sigma, right?

Comment: That is correct (the weighting happens automatically).